# List of elements of generic Type - Java

Tags: java, class, generics

i am not able to handle some kind of structure, I have to work with:

```
Class<? extends Node> nodesClass = gds.getNodeType();
List<nodesClass> nodes = new ArrayList();
```

Now eclipse doesn't accept "nodesClass". What is the code which creates a List of Instance of Type nodesClass?

Comment: `nodesClass` is a variable, not a type.

Comment: so how do i get the Class of the variable? getNodeType return a Class<? extend Node>, but i need a list of those instances?

Comment: You seem to want information at compile-time that's only known at run-time...

Comment: @barracuda317 Sounds like you're calling the wrong method. getNodeType is the type of the node. Is there a `getNode()` or `getValue()`? When you have an instance you can call `getClass()`.

Comment: You can't do that.  You can't have a generic where the thing between `<>` is a variable.

Comment: gds means GraphDataStructure and i want to fill a Graph according to this Strucure. There are no nodes in the structure definition. But whats the sense of getNodeType(), if i am not able to say something about the Type of the Nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get class type from the user by calling

`Class<? extends Node> nodesClass = gds.getNodeType();`

Then by using that class type given by the method `gds.getNodeType()` you want to create `ArrayList` object.

Instead of this you can go for `List<? extends Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();` so that to the `nodes` variable you can assign any `ArrayList` object with generic type that should be sub class to `Node` class.

But here the problem is you can not add any new objects to `nodes` variable i.e.

`nodes.add(new Node())` is illegal, but you can type secure that you can have only `List` object that is having generic type sub class to `Node` class.

If this answer is not appropriate to you let me know what is your exact requirement

Comment: `nodes` is completely useless here.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth that should be decided by the owner of the question not by you and same thing I have mentioned in my answer also.

Comment: No, it's determined by the fact that you can't do *anything useful* with it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do something useful with the list you are trying to create is by creating it as:

```
List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList();
```

Trying to create a list of `List<? extends Node>` will only make your empty list unusable - you won't be able to add anything to it.